# OpenERP : fetch record with same name

Tags: python, odoo

How can I retrieve records that have the same value of name in openerp (or same other field)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution of using a manual SQL query to group by `name` as suggested by Ruchir is probably the simplest, but a bit low-level. You can also do it using the `read_group()` API method that performs a similar `GROUP BY` query, but without bypassing access control mechanisms and model business logic.

The `read_group` method takes a search domain (similarly to `search()`), a list of fields to read (similarly to `read()`) and a list of fields to group by. This method is documented in the [OpenERP API](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html).
It returns an ordered list of dictionaries with the grouped data and some extra values, including the number of record in each group, stored in a key named `<grouped_field>_count`, which you could use to find duplicates.

For example if you look for duplicate `name` values, without any other search criterion:

```py
def duplicate_names(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    # Note: context not propagated for brevity of example
    groups = self.read_group(cr, uid, [], ['name'], ['name'])
    duplicate_names = [g['name'] for g in groups if g['name_count'] > 1]
    print "Duplicates names:", duplicate_names

    if duplicate_names:
        # It's easy to find out the IDs of duplicate records for each name,
        # here is for the first one
        duplicate_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('name', '=', duplicate_names[0])])
        print "Duplicate IDs for %r: %s" % (duplicate_names[0], duplicate_ids)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find duplicate records with a direct SQL query in the database. As an example, this is how you can find duplicate names in the Contact Addresses:

```
cr.execute("""
    SELECT name, id, partner_id FROM res_partner_address
    WHERE name in (SELECT name
                   FROM res_partner_address
                   GROUP BY name
                   HAVING (COUNT(name) > 1))""")

print cr.dictfetchall()
```

Instead of `cr.dictfetchall()` you can use `cr.fetchall()` to get the results as a list of tuples rather than dicts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific value for a field 'name' to be searched, then the domain to be searched is

```
domain = [('name', '=', your_value)]
```

If you have a list of values to be searched then

```
domain = [('name', 'in', list_of_values)]
```

If you want to search a field 'name' with similar value then

```
domain = [('name','ilike',your_value)]
```

Now you can search

```
our_pool = self.pool.get('your.obj.name')
ids = our_pool.search(cr, uid, domain, context=context)
```

Now you can browse the ids we get

```
our_objs = our_pool.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
```

Comment: The question was how to find records that have duplicate values in some field, such as name.

Answer (score -1):

You should first read the document first: http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html

For this question you will need first a 'search' then a 'browse' (or 'read') for example:

```
obj = self.pool.get('your.obj.name')
ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('name','=',your_value)], context=context)
records = obj.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

Comment: The question was how to find records that have duplicate values in some field, such as name.